# How to get HTML5 markup elements to display well in IE

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, markup

What is the best way to get HTML5 markup elements like `<header>`, `<section>`, and `<footer>` to display well in IE?

Usually, when I apply CSS to the HTML5 elements, the styling doesn't take place. But I have seen it done on other sites, like [colourfreak.com](http://www.colourfreak.com), and would like some help.

I think it has something to do with the selectors not accepting new tag names. So something like this wouldn't work:

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

A detailed explanation or nice article would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What other sites? Are they using http://css3pie.com/?

Comment: other site: http://www.colourfreak.com/

Comment: Add it (and others) to your question.

Comment: ...Umm wait a minute. Is this what makes everything work beautifully: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->` I didn't want to have to use javascript. :(

Comment: Initially, it looks like they're using `#` CSS selectors to default to an element, regardless of element type (IE supports the `#` ID selector on all elements back to IE6).

Comment: As far as your last comment, using a conditional to allow for IE9 to take advantage of HTML5 techniques sounds about right, but I can't say for sure. Welcome to designing for IE. :)

Comment: “I didn't want to have to use javascript. :(” — Tough. Internet Explorer won’t let you do anything with elements it doesn’t know about unless you create them via JavaScript first. The same is true for the `<abbr>` element, which was part of HTML 4, but wasn’t recognised by Internet Explorer 6.

Answer (score 9):

For IE we have to create new HTML5 elements with JS. Create new file, name it for example html5.js and include this script in your `<head>` area. All will be fine.

```
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('details');
document.createElement('figcaption');
document.createElement('figure');
document.createElement('footer');
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('hgroup');
document.createElement('main');
document.createElement('menu');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('summary');
```

This is required only for IE, so you can use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Because of these elements are displayed as inline elements, you'll probably want to add this rule In your CSS file:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer,
header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary { display: block; }
```

Comment: Based on normalize.css, the following list of elements would be even  more complete: article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary (otherwise you still risk missing out on elements)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the HTML5 Shiv...

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also you could use the HTML5 boilerplate... (Includes the HTML 5 shiv)

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: Also, as Webars said you will need to apply "display:block;" to all html 5 elements when using HTML5 shiv, as IE will not give them any default styling. If you're using boilerplate this will already be done for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure [Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/) will solve your problem and alot of other cross-browser issues with CSS3 as well.